# Как генерировать hashCode для первичного ключа в таблице PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Я хочу использовать для первичного ключа в таблице PostgreSQL хеш-функцию так, чтобы генерировал это значение сам PostgreSQL.

1. Возможно ли генерировать hashCode при помощи PostgreSQL?
2. Принято ли вообще так делать? Или это плохая идея?
3. Если ответы на первые два вопроса да, то как это сделать?

Comment: А чего вы хотите этим достичь ?

Comment: И надеюсь вы понимаете, что сам хеш первичным ключом не может быть в принципе. потому что любой хеш допускает коллизии, т.е. одинаковое значение хеша для двух разных входных данных

Comment: @Mike я смотрел уроки технострима от мэйлру по поздгресс и  ребята там объяснили что для безопасности лучше использовать хэш потому что это не дает потенциальным злоумышлиникам понять по первичному ключу сколько в таблице записей а на коллизии можно не обращать внимания потому что шанс на них один к семи миллиардам. Вот я и задался вопросом как мне это реализовать.

Comment: Теперь понятно почему все проекты мейлру так глючат. Нельзя полагаться на вероятности. id в базе лучше делать обычным автоинкрементом. Благо стандартные механизмы БД как раз на это рассчитаны. Если важна безопасность то при передаче клиенту шифруете свои id любым обратимым блочным шифром и отдаете клиенту уже зашифрованное значение, кодированное в base64 (или даже base85). Оно будет выглядеть абсолютно случайным. А при получении запроса обратно просто расшифровываете. Не зная вашего ключа шифрования подобрать следующее значение или узнать хотя бы примерную величину невозможно

Comment: хотя можно еще uuid позаморачиватся, но не вижу смысла раздувать БД в объеме. вам же на эти первичные ключи еще ссылаться из других таблиц ...

Comment: И еще один плюс от шифрования - вы можете проверить корректность значения еще до обращения в БД, хоть в фильтр DDos встраивайте проверку. Некую строку к значению id добавляете перед шифрованием. И после дешифровки убеждаетесь, что она корректна

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `md5()`
2. Зависит от задачи
3. ..

Пример:

```
t=# create table so78 (h text primary key default md5(now()::text),i int);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 9.060 ms
t=# insert into so78 (i) select 1;
INSERT 0 1
Time: 3.317 ms
t=# insert into so78 (i) select 1;
INSERT 0 1
Time: 6.169 ms
t=# select * from so78;
                h                 | i
----------------------------------+---
 2e346ec46b4ae31f54bf3ad3d90d3183 | 1
 356c21c892c0e523395a6330dff3b4ce | 1
(2 rows)

Time: 0.205 ms
```

так же может лучше uuid?.. Хотя и его можно использовать похоже:

```
t=# select md5(now()::text)::uuid;
                 md5
--------------------------------------
 1060bdc9-cff8-955c-71bb-7c62d4543965
(1 row)

Time: 1.218 ms
```

или лучше [без изобретения колеса](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.6/uuid-ossp) `uuid_generate_v4`. как default PK его...

Answer (score 1):

По причинам, изложенным Mike в комментарии к вопросу, категорически не стоит делать первичный ключ из хэша по причине его "неуникальности" (вследствие коллизии). При небольшом количестве данных может сложиться впечатление, что уникальность есть, но это, очевидно, обманчиво, и проблема с дублированием ключа может "вылезти" неожиданно.

Не зная деталей Вашей задачи, не могу судить о целесообразности использования хэширования как такового и советовать что либо.